# How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I need to implement splash screen in my honeycomb app.
I use this code in activity's onCreate to show splash:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
getActionBar().hide();
```

and this code to show main UI after sometime:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getActionBar().show();
```

But *before* onCreate is called and splash appears, there is small amount of time when action bar shown.

How can I make action bar invisible?

I tried to apply theme to activity without action bar:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

but in that case getActionBar() always returns null and I found no way to show it again.

Comment: For `Theme.AppCompat.Light` ... use this [answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/1364896

Answer (score 336):

Setting `android:windowActionBar="false"` truly disables the ActionBar but then, as you say, `getActionBar();` returns null.
This is solved by:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.splash); // be sure you call this AFTER requestFeature
```

This creates the ActionBar and immediately hides it before it had the chance to be displayed.

But now there is another problem. After putting `windowActionBar="false"` in the theme, the Activity draws its normal Window Title instead of an ActionBar.
If we try to avoid this by using some of the `*.NoTitleBar` stock themes or we try to put `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in our own theme, it won't work.
The reason is that the ActionBar *depends* on the Window Title to display itself - that is the ActionBar is a transformed Window Title.
So the trick which can help us out is to add one more thing to our Activity theme xml:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>
```

This will make the Window Title with zero height, thus practically invisible .

In your case, after you are done with displaying the splash screen you can simply call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getActionBar().show();
```

and you are done. The Activity will start with no ActionBar flickering, nor Window Title showing.

**ADDON:**
If you show and hide the ActionBar multiple times maybe you have noticed that the *first* showing is *not* animated. From then on showing and hiding are animated. If you want to have animation on the first showing too you can use this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    // delaying the hiding of the ActionBar
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post(new Runnable() {     
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
    });
```

The same thing can be achieved with:

```
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getActionBar().hide();
```

but it may need some extra logic to check if this is the first showing of the Activity.

The idea is to delay a little the hiding of the ActionBar. In a way we let the ActionBar be shown, but then hide it immediately. Thus we go beyond the first non-animated showing and next showing will be considered second, thus it will be animated.

As you may have guessed there is a chance that the ActionBar *could* be seen before it has been hidden by the delayed operation. This is actually the case. Most of the time nothing is seen but yet, once in a while, you can see the ActionBar flicker for a split second.

In any case this is not a pretty solution, so I welcome any suggestions.

**Addition** for v7 support actionbar user, the code will be:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: @newton_guima yes, it does work. Just remember to use supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)

Comment: @Cleric - How do you make all this to work with `setTheme`? Because your answer works great if I set the theme from the Manifest, but if I do it in `onCreate` (in my case the theme depends on a preference for light of dark theme) the default holo action bar flashes before the one I set in my theme anyway. But maybe this is worth another complete SO question.

Comment: @dentex There is no problem to set your own theme with `setTheme` in `onCreate` and _still_ use the one defined in the Manifest. In other words, the Manifest theme serves _only_ to disable the ActionBar and hide the TitleBar _before_ `onCreate` is reached.

Comment: @Cleric Thanks. I resolved my issue setting `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` into the Manifest and then `setTheme(R.style.MyTheme)` in main activity's `onCreate`; This ensures (in Android 4+) avoiding the flash of the default holo `ActionBar` before the one I defined in my theme (I arrived here looking for a way to workaround this; I actually don't need any splash-screen).

Comment: I call `getSupportActionBar().hide();` after `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` and everything blows up with a NPE. Any ideas? Problem with `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: @Cleric it works for Activity, But I have an Activity with two fragments like login fragment and homescreen fragment,I want to hide actionbar on only login fragment. I used getSupportActionBar().hide();  but the Actionbar display for few seconds then only it hides.I think overriding activity theme hides on both fragments.

Comment: why not just create a separate SplashActivity with a different theme?

Comment: `ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout`

Comment: @loeschg: I had the same problem and found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20315456/3514976

Comment: simply super! This one is most important for my Xamarin project.. Thank u

Answer (score 52):

Using this simple code in your .class file to hide action bar

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 37):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, then use Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar Theme in your Activity

```
<activity 
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: The same applies for standard Android 3+ ActionBar (no Sherlock):
`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoActionBar">`.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to Ilya's question. Setting the theme to be `Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar` will mean calling `getActionBar()` or `getSupportActionBar()` (to subsequently show the action bar) returns null...

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk When I use that line in the manifest, I get this error: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/
 Theme.NoActionBar').`

Comment: @SiKni8 Are you sure you are using API13+ library for your application?

Comment: Somehow Eclipse loaded 3.0 and it caused an error. Finally fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: The "Light" version of this that worked for me: `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: The Holo theme has a NoActionBar too: `android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 19):

Create two styles:

```
<style name="AppThemeNoBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Set AppThemeNoBar as application theme and AppThemeBar to the activity where you want to show the ActionBar.﻿
Using two styles you wont see the Action bar while views are loading.

Check this link [Android: hide action bar while view load](https://plus.google.com/105092052613467789971/posts/gs8EKC35YjL)

Comment: This does not work on Android 2.3.3  with AppCompat.  ActionBar is shown.  However, this works on i.e. KitKat.

Answer (score 17):

Hi I have a simple solution by using 2 themes

1. Splash screen theme (add it to the manifest):

   `<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
   </style>`
2. normal theme (add it in your activity by setTheme(R.style.Theme)):

   `<style name="Theme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo"> <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
   </style>`

To support SDK 10:

```
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(R.style.Theme);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ...........
      ...........
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I was also trying to hide Action Bar on Android 2.2, but none of these solution worked. Everything ends with a crash. I checked the DDMS LOg, It was telling me to use 'Theme.AppCompat'.At last I Solved the problem by changing the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"`Line

into `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`and it worked, but the the Interface was dark.

then i tried `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` and finally got what i wanted.

After that when I Searched about 'AppCompat' on [Developer Site I got This.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

So I think the Solution for Android 2.2 is

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And Sorry for my bad English Like Always.

Answer (score 12):

Best result to me was to create an activity with ThemeNoTitleBar and without content as launcher. Then this activity call directly to the other.

Of course if you want you can add content to the Splash Activity but in my case I just wanted to show application directly.

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //start StartActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 9):

If you use one `Activity` included a splash screen, then you can do this if you use `SherlockActionBar`

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

After the splash screen you can show it again with ...

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

It should be the same with native `ActionBar` of Android.

Answer (score 6):

@Clerics solution works. But this appears to also be an issue with some of googles native apps: googles, play store, talk. Also other big apps like skype.

**EDIT**: Bellow solution have given me problem for actionbarsherlock on api < 4.0, the reason being setTheme doesn't work pre ice cream sandwich

Add following in your manifest within you application or activity tags:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"
```

And then in your main activity:

```
    // Set theme
    setTheme(R.style.YOUR_THEME);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title);

    // Start regular onCreate()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 6):

best and simple

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Answer (score 6):

2015, using support v7 library with AppCompat theme, set this theme for your Activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppStyled" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_indigo_100</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_indigo_500</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_red_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/md_white_1000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_purple_500</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

For `Splashscreen` you should use this line in `manifest` and don't use `getActionBar()`

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and once when Splash `Activity` is finished in the main `Activity` use below or nothing

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Comment: This actually works if you use a different theme for the splash page then the main page of your application.  Just use the android:theme="@style/mytheme" for both the Main Activity (your splash screen) and the first activity of your application that is not the splash screen swapping out themes.

Comment: This gives an error at current API levels: "Attribute is missing the android namespace prefix." `<item android:name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>` gets rid of this error, but I don't know whether it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me:

Below gets rid of activity's title bar

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Below eliminates the notification bar to make the activity go full-screen

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

(Full Example Below)
Take note: These methods were called before we set the content view of our activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Sets Application to full screen by removing action bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // without this check, we would create a new fragment at each orientation change!
        if (null == savedInstanceState)
            createFragment();
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify why this works or why you think this should work. Just pasting code does not make for a complete answer.

Comment: @Kris, Oh I see what you mean, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this may be handy
add this to your manifest

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

cheers

Comment: Why to post something not as great as the top answer in such an old question?

Comment: the 'top answer' didnt help me, so found myself with this answer and posted it here.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I find after reading all the available options is set main theme without ActionBar and then set up MyTheme in code in parent of all Activity.

Manifest:

```
<application
...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
...>
```

BaseActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.GreenHoloTheme);
}
```

This way helps me to avoid ActionBar when application start!

Answer (score 1):

The solutions already posted came with the sideffect, that the first .show() call did not animate the ActionBar for me.
I got another nice solution, which fixed that:

Create a transparent drawable - something like that:

> ```
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <solid
>        android:color="#00000000" />
> </shape>
> ```

Set the actual actionbar background to a invisible custom view which you set on the actionbar:

> ```
> getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_layout);
>       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
>               ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
> ```

Set the transparent background for the actionbar in onCreate:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_transparent));
```

Imortant: Don't hide the actionbar immediately in onCreate, but with a little delay later - e.g. when the layout is finished with creation:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                }
            });
```

Before your first .show() call set the custom view visible:

> ```
> _actionbarRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
> getSupportActionBar().show();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have null because you are using the **support library**, instead of `getActionBar()` you need to call `getSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your MainActivity in the onCreate function.

```
val actionBar = supportActionBar?.apply { hide() }
```

Comment: it is work on androidx. Just add after _setContentView()_ this row `supportActionBar?.apply { hide() }`

Answer (score 0):

Put your splash screen in a separate activity and use [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) from your main activity's `onCreate` method to display it. This works because, according to the docs:

> As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity.

You should probably do this only if the argument to `onCreate` is `null` (indicating a fresh launch of your activity, as opposed to a restart due to a configuration change).

Comment: This does not work. When onCreate() starts, action bar is already visible. This is clearly seen in debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had still error with null pointer and finally it helped when I called first getWindow().requestFeature() and then super.onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getActionBar().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could simply set splash `Activity` with `NoActionBar` 
and set your main `activity` with action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is two make the first activity as blank activity and the content you want to put and then after some time fire another activity.
By following this way you can make the first activity as your splash screen without action bar or anything.
Heres my first activity

```
package com.superoriginal.rootashadnasim.syllabus;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class first_screen extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);


    final Handler h=new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new     Intent(getApplicationContext(),DrawerChooseBranchMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    },2000);

}
}
```

After that you can put any of your activity as first activity
If you want no action bar in any screen then just add this in your styles

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio provide in build template for full screen, if you use Android studio you can follow below step to implement full screen activity.

[image: First Step to Create new Activity]

[image: Select select Full screen Activity]

Done. Android studio did your job, now you can check code for full screen.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way I used
Go to java file, after `onCreate`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        // Take instance of Action Bar 
        // using getSupportActionBar and 
        // if it is not Null 
        // then call hide function 
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) { 
            getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I realise that posting links are not the best way to do things, but I highly recommend you read the following documentation from Google themselves. This is the official android doc on how to control your system ui (things like actionbar, nav bar etc). Unfortunately the info is too much to post directly,  but after reading this you will understand exactly how to show and hide features no matter what version you are developing for, its so simple!

Incase the link ever changes, it can be found under the official android documentation under **training** -> **getting started** -> **Best practices for user interface** -> **managing the system ui**

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/index.html

[image]

Answer (score -4):

you can use this :

`getSupportActionBar().hide();` if it doesn't work try this one :

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

if above doesn't work try like this :

in your directory = res/values/style.xml , open style.xml -> there is attribute `parent` change to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

if all of it doesn't work too. i don't know anymore. but for me it works.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().hide(); was mentioned in the highest voted answer, getActionBar().hide(); was mentioned in the question, and  DarkActionBar was mentioned in Son Nguyen Thanh's answer. Plus this question is 4 years old and already has several high voted answers.