# Android- hide actionbar during startup and then show it again?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My android app has tab navigation using an action bar. It works well, but it bothers me that during the first boot of the app, a small default action bar briefly shows up before being replaced by the real, tab-navigation action bar. My onCreate starts like this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set up the actionbar
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
.
.
.
```

What do I have to do so that the real actionbar will be initialized without a small default one briefly showing before it does on startup?

Thanks

Comment: Is this something you are looking for: [How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

Answer (score 5):

Hide during startup

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

After you can show it again with ...

```
 getSupportActionBar().show();
```

It should be the same with native ActionBar of Android.

you should use this line in manifest and don't use getActionBar()

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

and once it's finished in the main Activity use below or nothing

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Comment: How do I add the XML you specified so that the app boots with

<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

But then switches to

<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

After the main activity starts?

Comment: I've tried assigning the application itself a theme with no actionbar, but assign the activity with a theme with one (using android:windowActionBar). It still boots with a default actionbar, and only then initializes itself as the real navigation actionbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again?rq=1 watch this link

Answer (score 4):

put this for your activity manifest definition:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            >
```

then inside your oncreate do this to show the actual theme  you want used:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using action bar sherlock and you want to toggle this from a FragmentActivity, then you call

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```