# Hiding Navigation bar

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I hide the navigation bar in an Android app?

My tablet uses Android 4.1.2

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I am not a android developer, but as far as I heard, you can't hide it and Google has disabled that option to prevent application from abusing the facility.

Comment: Simple as a Google Research : https://www.google.fr/search?q=Hide%20actionbar%20android&rlz=1C1ASUT_enFR469FR469&oq=Hide%20actionbar%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2j69i60j0.5194j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android- hide actionbar during startup and then show it again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469721/android-hide-actionbar-during-startup-and-then-show-it-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recommended by design guidelines, however if you are definitely sure you need to do it, you can refer to this post: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: Well I couldn't find a real solution but I found this amazing app in the android store and it does good work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreen&hl=en