# Unfortunately App has stopped, while trying to add Tabs

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written an app in which i am fetching list of facebook friends, but now i have decided to add one more feature in my existing app - Multiple Tabs,

and i have also written necessary code to get that, but whenever i Run my program getting - Unfortunately App has stopped

I guess the below line is creating problem, but not getting a way how can i remove this issue?

```
this.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(false);
```

*ActionBarActivity.java:*

```
  protected void setDisplayShowIconEnabled(boolean bool) {
    mActionBarHelper.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(bool);
}
```

*ActionBarHelperICS.java:*

```
     @Override
public void setDisplayShowIconEnabled(boolean bool) {
    mActivity.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(bool);
}
```

*SplashScreen.java:*

```
  public void onRequestReceived(int result, String message) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRequestReceived(" + result + ")");
    if(isFinishing())
        return;
    switch (result) {
    case FacebookRequest.COMPLETED:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        intent.putExtra("FRIENDS", message);
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < DELAY) {
            try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, FRIENDS_LIST_ACTIVITY);
        isLoadingFriends = false;
        break;
    case FacebookRequest.IO_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION:
    case FacebookRequest.FACEBOOK_ERROR:
        FacebookUtility.displayMessageBox(this, this.getString(R.string.friends_error));
        onButton();
        break;
    }
}
```

*Main.java:*

```
 public class Main extends TabActivity {


private TabHost tabHost;
private final String FRIENDS_TAB = "friends";
private final String MONTH_TAB = "month";
private final String WEEK_TAB = "week";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    TabSpec contactSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(FRIENDS_TAB).setIndicator(
            "FB Friends", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.friends))
            .setContent(new Intent(Main.this, FriendsList.class));

    TabSpec monthSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(MONTH_TAB).setIndicator(
            "This Month", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.month))
            .setContent(new Intent(Main.this, FriendsList.class));

    TabSpec weekSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(WEEK_TAB).setIndicator(
            "This Week", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.week))
            .setContent(new Intent(Main.this, FriendsList.class));


    tabHost.addTab(contactSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(monthSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(weekSpec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
  }
```

*FriendsList.java:*

```
   public class FriendsList extends ActionBarActivity  implements FacebookRequest, OnItemClickListener {
private static String LOG_TAG = "FriendsList";
private static JSONArray jsonArray;
private static ListView friendsList;
private Handler mHandler;
  private Button saveGreeting;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    try {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_list_screen);
    try {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        setProgressBarInDVisibility(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
   this.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(false);
    init();

    saveGreeting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    saveGreeting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        customGreeting(v);
        }
    });
}
```

*Logcat Report:*

```
     01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist/com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.Main.onCreate(Main.java:37)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  ... 11 more
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.ActionBarHelperICS.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(ActionBarHelperICS.java:38)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.ActionBarActivity.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(ActionBarActivity.java:85)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.FriendsList.onCreate(FriendsList.java:56)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-14 16:18:02.954: E/AndroidRuntime(960):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: mActionBarHelper on `ActionBarActivity.java` is initializated?

Comment: in the log shows a NullPointerException on the line 38 of ActionBarHelperICS.java  `com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.ActionBarHelperICS.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(ActionBarHelperICS.java:38)` , I think this line is `mActionBarHelper.setDisplayShowIconEnabled(bool);` on your code, so the most probably cause is that mActionBarHelper was null.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again