# How to hide actionbar while scrolling down a webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar

I am developing an android app. In the app there is one webview which fetches data from the internet and show it to the user. But actionbar is consuming some screen space. What i want to do is hide the actionbar while user scroll down in the webview. I have searched everywhere on the internet but could not find a proper way to do this. I am using appcompat actionbar and my min sdk is 10.

Comment: Providing some code will help people assist you.

Comment: @nomistic Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActionBar` with `Overlay Mode`. Enable it by calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` before `setContentView()`. And hide the `ActionBar` using `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Now for `Scrolling` event for `WebView` you can follow this answer in [SO](http://Scroll%20Listener%20for%20WebView%20in%20Android)

**Edit:**

For Hiding ActionBar

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

For Showing

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chinmoy. But i don't want to overlay the actionbar. I just want to hide it when user scroll down and want it back when user scrolls up.

Comment: You need to use overlay because whenever you call getActionBar().hide(); you will see a jump on your screen. To remove this problem you need to add actionbar as overlay. And for hiding action bar getActionBar().hide(); is the method and for showing getActionBar().show();

Comment: Okay thanks Chinmoy. I will implement this method and mark your answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: before activity created not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526144/actionbarcompat-hide-actionbar-before-activity-is-created-bug

Comment: The link doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into `CoordinatorLayout` which is part of the new android design support library and enables you to collapse and expand the actionbar on child scrolling events.

Comment: Where can i find CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: Here's an example: [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)
You also have to add the dependency in your gradle file:
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: Don't think web views are supported for CoordinatorLayouts yet.

Comment: place the WebView inside NestedScrollView. it will work. And of course they are inside CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Don't use NestedScrollView inside Webview, it causes height issues plus google also doesn't recommend to use it with webview.

Comment: CoordinatorLayout approach causes webview scroll issues.