# getFragmentManager vs getSupportFragmentManager ERROR

Tags: android, android-fragments

i need help for this . I realize sth very strange about this. In order to disable the Action bar (Title) , i need to add in this code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

So this only works I change from

```
extends AppCompatActivity
```

To this

```
extends Activity
```

**So after changing that, I got error for the getFragmentManager.**

Please have a look at the screenshot. And let me know if u guys have any idea wads going on? THx

[image]

Comment: You need to make your fragment to extends android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.
`AppCompatActivity` is v4 library therefore required to use v4 functions

And to use it in `Activity` instead of `Activity` change it to `FragmentActivity`. Then you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I did imported that but it still doesn't work. Same error prompt

Comment: check out the updated answer... You need to use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

Answer (score 3):

***requestWindowFeature()*** is not supported in ***AppCompatActivity*** thats why you could not use that method with ***AppCompatActivity***.

Also if you are using ***AppCompatActivity*** you need to use ***SupportFragment*** and if you use Activity then use ***Fragment***.

Comment: requestWindowFeature() is not supported in AppCompatActivity   , Any solution for this ? so how to disable the Action bar ?

Comment: see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526144/actionbarcompat-hide-actionbar-before-activity-is-created-bug

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`,

then you must use getSupportFragmentManager.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Compat method `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of the regular one.

That's because it returns an object of type *android.app.FragmentManager* which is the type of the object where you're trying to store it.

If you use the regular method `getFragmentManager()` it'll return an object of type *android.app.FragmentManager*, which is an incompatible type.

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean *Support. Edited now. I was thinking in Compatibility and Support and I've mislead.