# how to call getActionBar() in TouchImageView class from Dreddik

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I use the code from https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery to implement pinch zoom for imageView. It works great. But now I want to call getActionBar.show() and hide() inside the touchEvent of TouchImageView class.

The problem is this class extends ImageView so I cannot call getActionBar().

Any advice?

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help you...

```
public static class TouchView extends ImageView {

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```