# Android Splashscreen - action bar comes for a moment and disappears

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, splash-screen

In the app I am developing,I am implementing a splashscreen This splashscreen comes at the start of the app. When the splashscreen is launched, the `action bar` is visible for a small moment say half a second and then disappears. I am not sure why this is happening. Could any one please help me in resolving this issue. I have implemented the following code in the `manifest file`.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.trycatch.SplashscreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:noHistory = "true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And below is the activity file snippet

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Could anyone please help me. Thanks for your time.

PS: I am using `sherlock actionbar` library

Comment: remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` from manifest file

Comment: Thanks for that. I did that. This makes the action bar to appear in the splashscreen.

Comment: you want action bar showing or not?

Comment: I dont want it showing. It is not showing. I am happy with that. But is coming for a fraction of a second and disappears.

Comment: @TimothyRajan did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope. This happens in my S3. I am using HTC desire. It is not happening in that device. Might be mobile specific. Clueless about it.

Comment: Hey @TimothyRajan I too have the same problem but none of the below answers worked for me... If you found the solution please comment it below

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in the activity(that means in your java file) before setContentView()

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your android manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.abc.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar" ></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to disappear Action Bar:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
 getActionBar().hide();

 setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)