# how to hide action bar in swipe view with tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's [a link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)
I want to hide the action bar (application title bar)/full screen activity of application how can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the action bar by adding `<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` to your manifest, or programmatically :

```
getActionBar().hide();

// with abs
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again) may be helpfull