# FragmentPagerAdapter, hide and show Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE base on fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I want to emulate snapchat. Where the camera fragment have no title bar using:

onCreate

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

But when I swipe to the left fragment or right fragment I want the title bar to appear.

How do I do this?

Thank you for your time.

Clarify:

When the pager switch, to another item, or the main activity switch fragment I want to show the title bar.

I'm currently using FragmentPagerAdapter to emulate snapchat. Where you start at the camera fragment and if you swipe/fling left or right, you get another fragment. The transition between fragments is carousel like, unlike calling activity with another activity where the transition between the activity is more of a popup.

Unfortunately, switching between fragment, doesn't invoke different onCreate hookmethod so I cannot hide or show the window title depending on the fragment (I can do this with activity). So I want to know how would I do this with fragment.

I'm using compat v4.

Comment: may be you can use actionbar instead in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that you do something like this

See here : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html
           http://blog.grio.com/2014/02/androids-hiding-of-the-system-bar-fixed.html

- Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower,
- Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher

  ```
  ViewPager mViewPager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void onPageSelected(int position) {

              if(position == 0 ){
                  showStatusBar() ;
              }else {
                  hideStatusBar();
              }

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

          }
      });
  ```

  }

  ```
  private void hideStatusBar() {
      // Hide status bar
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }

  private void showStatusBar() {
   // Show status bar
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hide and show methods your `actionbar` each time you slide left or right in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`

**sample:**

```
        getActionBar().hide(); //will hide the actionbar
        getActionBar().show(); //will show the actionbar
```