# Full screen Videoview doesn't hide menu bar during rotation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-videoview

I'm working on a youtube / rtmp live video app using videoview and samples codes from all over the net so fall i have the app working but I'm facing a problem when i change orientation the live video rotates and expands fine but it doesn't go to a complete full screen, how can i setup a way to go to a complete full screen only when I go into landscape mode?

my main activity.

```
    progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", " Cargando vídeo por favor espere...", true);
    progressdialog.setCancelable(true);

    final VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    String vidAddress = "http://videourl/playlist.m3u8";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri); 

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);

    vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            progressdialog.dismiss();
           vidView.start();


        }
    });
```

main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/list_playlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

</GridView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
</RelativeLayout>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

[image: vertical]
[image: horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

In your `OrientationChange` event or whatever event gets the video to `fullscreen`, You will have to **hide** the `Status Bar` and the `Action Bar`. This way when you change orientation, the Status Bar and Action Bar will be hidden allowing the video to go in fullscreen.

*How to Hide the Status Bar:*

**1.** [See this from Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

*How to Hide the Action Bar:*

**2.** [See This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to kind of solve the issue by applying the following codes but still wont go to a complete full screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

in onConfigurationChanged set rules to the video frame like this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
if (newConfig.orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rel.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, R.id.relativeFrame);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, R.id.relativeFrame);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, R.id.relativeFrame);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, R.id.relativeFrame);
        rel.setLayoutParams(lp);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

remember to remove rules when configuration changes back to prtrait

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rel.getLayoutParams();
        lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rel.setLayoutParams(lp);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```