# When I show action-bar (from hidden) the first time there is no reveal animination - How fix?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

**My Problem is:**

If you show and hide the ActionBar multiple times maybe you have noticed that the first showing is not animated. From then on showing and hiding are animated.

My issue is described described in this stackoverflow thread, in the section refereed to as ADDON (This thread does not solve my problem) - [stackoverflow.com/a/14167949/4424557](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167949/4424557) - I am not facing the same issue as this user, although the point made by the answerer explains my issue

**How do I fix the above, so that even the first time it is revealed animation does take place?**

To explain the animation I'm referring to -

**Look at this youtube clip**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gZ_y7MqEGM

(The animation above works, but in my case on primary reveal the animation doesn't occur)

**The code I'm using to reveal the actionbar is below:**

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

            actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

---

```
actionBar.hide();
```

Or

```
actionBar.show();
```

Comment: i don't know what animation you mean, but it sounds like the animation occurs when its hidden. cant you create the ActionBar when you actually need it?

Comment: I've updated the question above, to show a youtube clip explaining this. I reveal and hide when I need it.

Comment: does this help you? invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: No, I've placed the above suggested code prior to each actionBar.hide(); or actionBar.show();   and the issue still occurs

Comment: i think it should go right AFTER show();

Comment: Just tried that too. Issue still occurs

Comment: Just to clarify, the animation DOES happen, only when it does, your actionbar is hidden, so you don't see it. You have to find a way to recreate this actionbar, or make what you are trying to do a new activity(which you probably should, but i might be wrong)

Comment: No, when the actionbar is first revealed (actionbar.show()), there is no animation happening. - Which is the problem. After this first reveal animation does work. But the first time it doesn't

Comment: did you try putting hide and show right after eachother?

Comment: I have and similarly in that case, the first time the actionbar is revealed there is no animation

Comment: btw, i can't see it in your video, because in the video the animation happens everytime. Its already there when the video starts, so i cant see the animation not happening

Comment: It's not my video, it was one I found on Youtube showing what animation I'm refering to.

Comment: and when it DOES happen you are using show(); ?

Comment: Yes, as similarly described in this stackoverflow thread, in the section refereed to as ADDON (This thread does not solve my problem) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14167949/4424557 - I am not facing the same issue as this user, although the point made by the answerer explains my issue

Comment: thanks for explaining, you might want to edit your question with the information you have gathered so far so others don't have to browse through the comments

Comment: I have, after having read that thread. Do you now have any idea, for how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the hide or show functions does what it says, but will NOT 'animate' it. In order to do so you could use a Interpolator.

I'd suggest you use the new Toolbar. Its really easy! ActionBar is now deprecated. With a toolbar you could do it like:

on Show:

```
toolbar.animate().translation(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
```

on Hide:

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbarHeight).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
```

Personally, I've done a similar implementation for a Floating Action Button (FAB) [here](http://blog.grafixartist.com/implement-floating-action-button-fab-part-2/) by using a custom ScrollListener. The same can be modified for Toolbar.

PS: What you're trying to achieve is also known as the [Quick Return Pattern.](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt)