# Hide action bar for small screen

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I am working on an android aap and i want to hide action bar for small screen (240x320) only not for normal and large screen. Is it possible to hide if it is then how?

Comment: Use `getActionBar().hide()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then you need to get the dimenstion first..

here's how to get the dimension:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

[see answers here on how to get the screen dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

here's how to hide action bar

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
```

**Addition for v7** support actionbar user, the code will be:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

[see answers here on how to hide action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

Comment: This logic is perfect

Answer (score 2):

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower**

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
...
```

Or 
 Must be before setting the layout.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

For more information you may visit [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#40) .