# Android hiding custom ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using a custom background for my ActionBar. I followed the tutorial from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us).

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
  <resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want this ActionBar to be displayed on each activity, except the login .. so I hid the ActionBar from my login activity (tut from: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)):

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
```

In my manifest I added the custom theme ... like this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    >
```

When I run the application, I get the error: **You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity**

So I searched on stackoverflow for a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity). I had to extend Activity instead of ActionBarActivity. I did this, also on my **Login Activity**.

But now ... I can't hide the ActionBar anymore at my Login activity because it doesnt extend ActionBarActivity anymore .. so the following code:

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Won't work .. anyone have an idea how to still Hide the actionbar at the Login activity, but still with a working custom Actionbartheme?

**TL;DR**: I want to use a custom actionbar, but I want to hide it on my Login activity. I can let the actionbar work, but only If I let my Login activity extend from Activity, instead of ActionBarActivity - This causes the getSupportActionBar(); to stop working, So I can't hide the actionbar anymore.

Comment: You don't need to hide, just use another theme for your login activity. I'm trying to use support lib everywhere, so I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as my parent theme and set Toolbar as my action bar where I really need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a theme whose parent is `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`. Assign it to your login activity with `android:theme` parameter.

Comment: Worked perfectly, have been struggling for hours now. I will mark this answer as correct (4 Min remaining). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in onCreate Method before setContentView() method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // add this line

    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
```