# Setting the theme in an android application

Tags: android

I've gone through quite a bit and I'm still at a loss for what I need to do:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

I have the view set to use the "Dialog" theme in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2) and the application looks like this in the insepctor:

[image]

However looks completely different on my phone (Much larger resolution, but that's not the point).

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this effect?

Comment: You need to hide ActionBar. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again) help you.

Comment: @Rooney - Action bar is irrelevant.  Border style / android button up top is theme related.

Comment: @rasmeta - The question is as clear as I can make it. The theme being used in the inspector is different than the one being used on the compiled APK.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Android Manifest

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this in one of my activities and it is ok:

```
        <activity
        android:name="eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo.mapDialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" ><!--add this-->
        </activity>
```

maybe your android version doesn't support that.

Comment: Look at the picture of the device (This is from the inspector). Do you see the border around it?  The sliver indent. That's from the Dialog theme. :|

Comment: let me explain .. a use this , but in my nokia x android 4.1.2 api16 4" screen it doesn't show as dialog.. but in another device running 4.4.4 api19 5" screen it appears as dialog ..so try it in another device