# Unwanted Title bar android

Tags: android, titlebar

I want to remove this unwanted title bar

[image]

I cant remove this

i have tried

```
 this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Is there any Exception?

Comment: call it before setContentView

Comment: Use this  getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a title bar. This is ActionBar or Toolbar. You should extend your application theme from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`. Or just add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` to `<application/>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

That should sort it, replace Theme with your actual theme if required, this line goes within the `application` part of the manifest or can go where the activity is declared.

Comment: Gildors answer is better than mine, From your code I thought it as a TitleBar but Gildor believes it is an ActionBar or a ToolBar, please check out his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your content view AFTER you have written the two lines

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
```