# How to make full size view when using TextureView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-xml, android-textureview

I have developed a camera app using ,latest Camera 2 API,the camera preview is set to a Texture view, I set both width and height as Match_parent ,is there any other attributes needed to set ?how can I set the camera preview  in a full screen view??I am a beginner, I don't know how to set this,can anybody help??

```
   <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />
```

[image: This is the screen shot of my screen,I want to make it full screen]

Comment: Maybe this theme could be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577299/android-camera-preview-stretched

Answer (score 0):

Use a NoActionBar Theme for that activity. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again) answer can guide you to achieve that.

Comment: please see the screen shot,I have added

Comment: That one seems fine. Perhaps I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please use DisplayMetrics to get w/h you want

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
RelativeLayout preview_video_parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_video_parent);
LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) preview_video_parent
    .getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
layoutParams.height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
mTextureView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could be useful for you : get the camera sizes and set them to the texturuView like this:

```
Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Size previewSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
TextureView myTexture = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.texture); 
myTexture.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Here you could take a look at a complete example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textureview.htm